# Paver Unknown task error

Tags: python, django, deployment, paver

I am getting started with `paver` and I am not getting a basic command to run, I am not sure what I am missing.

### Docs

[Link to the documentation](https://paver.github.io/paver/index.html)

### Installation

```
pip install paver
```

After installation I am able to execute `paver` in commandline.

```
---> paver.tasks.help
Usage: paver [global options] taskname [task options] [taskname [taskoptions]]

Options:
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -n, --dry-run         don't actually do anything
  -v, --verbose         display all logging output
  -q, --quiet           display only errors
  -i, --interactive     enable prompting
  -f FILE, --file=FILE  read tasks from FILE [pavement.py]
  -h, --help            display this help information
  --propagate-traceback
                        propagate traceback, do not hide it under
                        BuildFailure(for debugging)
  -x COMMAND_PACKAGES, --command-packages=COMMAND_PACKAGES
                        list of packages that provide distutils commands

Tasks from paver.misctasks:
  generate_setup - Generates a setup.py file that uses paver behind the scenes
  minilib        - Create a Paver mini library that contains enough for a simple
    pavement.py to be installed using a generated setup.py
  paverdocs      - Open your web browser and display Paver's documentation.

Tasks from paver.tasks:
  help           - This help display.
```

### paverlib > tasks.py

```
@task
def testpaver():
    from nose.tools import set_trace;set_trace()
```

### paverlib > _ *init* _.py

```
import tasks
```

### Run

```
paver testpaver
Build failed: Unknown task: testpaver
```

What I am missing?

Comment: Did you solve the preblem?

Comment: check the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Paver looks for `pavement.py` as a source for task definitions.

Have you tried putting `testpaver` in there?